# NSPredicate specific case [substring of NSString property is contained in NSArray]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I got an object with two properties, `first_name` and `last_name`

I want to filter a `UITableView` based on a search string (the user searches for a name in the tableview).

Now. My code works fine as long as the user inputs no spaces, e.g "simon" but fails when the user includes them e.g. "simon be..".

In addition, no names appear until the full partial name is entered (which is obvious why when looking at the code) e.g. "simo" gives nothing but "simon" gives something.

Now I am looking for a predicate that can filter my array based on these two properties and the search query obtained.

**My Code:**

```
    // [@"simon", @"be.."]
    NSArray *searchStrings = [searchQuery componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_name IN %@ OR last_name IN %@ ", searchStrings, searchStrings];

    [self.connections filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

**My Question:** How can I write a predicate that checks if there is any substring in `first_name` or `last_name` that is contained in the `searchStrings` array?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a `BEGINSWITH` would be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: do you have any property which binds first and last name ?

Comment: Instead of `NSPredicate`, why don't you filter the array with a block?